# The insert failed. It conflicted with an identity range check constraint in database

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

Hi I know this has been posted before but the suggested fixes dont work for me.
I have a newly created publication I have the Publisher range size set to 10000 and the subscriber range set to 10000.
I have set the Range threshold percentage to 50.

However when I insert 7000 rows I get the error
The insert failed. It conflicted with an identity range check constraint in database

Can anyone give me any pointers as to how to resolve this.

Comment: Check out this too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2189938/634642

Answer (score -1):

try inserting 2-4 thousand records at a time - that is the cleanest way to do it.

Otherwise you need to start changing range sizes, threshold percentages and possibly manually forcing a new address range (which will waste identities).